# A way to pin a header line when scrolling?

Tags: scrolling, header-line

Is there a way to pin a line at the top of the window, so that it stays there when scrolling? I'm writing a log viewer in Emacs Lisp, and I display each record with the fields padded so that it displays as a table. I'd like the header labels to stay visible, while the other rows scroll.

```
Time                         Level  Component  Message    
2023-01-12 22:48:02.02.2422  Debug  Thing      Blah blah blah 1 2 3
2023-01-12 22:48:02.02.2421  Info   Foo        some message
2023-01-12 22:48:02.02.2420  Error  Thing      another message 
...
```

Comment: As far as I know/remember, a [header line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html) does not scroll. However, I guess you might be more interested in [tabulated list mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tabulated-List-Mode.html) or the new [vtable](https://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2022/04/13/more-vtable-fun/) if you are using Emacs version > 28.

Comment: I'll look into that, and those modes. I have another feature where I use special 'start' and 'end' log records to create sections of the table that can be expanded/collapsed, mirroring the program's function call tree. So it's a "tree table". I don't know if tabulated list mode handles that.

Comment: I guess not indeed... so then I guess you can simply use the header line.

Comment: @dalanicolai: I don't know if this is a duplicate but if not, adding a good answer here might be helpful for future requests such as this.

Comment: I could not easily find a duplicate post, so I have created a very short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the [header-line-format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html) variable to your preferred format.
The header line uses the same format as the [mode line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html), so that it could be a simple string if you prefer.

As you are creating a table, you might also be interested in [tabulated-list-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tabulated-List-Mode.html) or the [vtable](https://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2022/04/13/more-vtable-fun/) package.